# jstack 100% CPU

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu, jrun, jstack

So I got stuck trying to figure out why our application will occasionally consume 100% CPU.  I've read several very helpful stackovertflow post, but I think to be on the safe side I would like to get some advice...guidance... assistance...whatever.  Really what this comes down too is my inexperience looking through stack traces.  I would really appreciate if someone could point out the possible culprit here as well as show me so pointers so I can better understand this.

The noteworthy threads (so it would seem to me) are ones waiting for Monitors:

```
I get four of these threads consistently jndi-0 - jndi-4

    "jndi-0" prio=6 tid=0x000000001113e000 nid=0x187c waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000012a9f000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:388)
        - waiting to lock  (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
        at jrun.servlet.network.NetworkService.accept(NetworkService.java:356)
        at jrun.naming.NamingNetworkService.accept(NamingNetworkService.java:115)
        at jrun.naming.NamingNetworkService.createRunnable(NamingNetworkService.java:141)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.createRunnable(ThreadPool.java:287)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.createRunnable(ThreadPool.java:349)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.createRunnable(ThreadPool.java:241)
        at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:62)
       Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

```
    "jrpp-298" prio=6 tid=0x0000000014730800 nid=0xdd4 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000001cc4b000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at coldfusion.runtime.LocalScope.put(LocalScope.java:247)
        - waiting to lock  (a coldfusion.runtime.VariableScope)
        at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_setValidatedSimpleName(NeoPageContext.java:1339)
        at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_setValidatedDottedName(NeoPageContext.java:1297)
        at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.setValidatedAttribute(NeoPageContext.java:524)
        at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.setAttribute(NeoPageContext.java:392)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._set(CfJspPage.java:369)
        at cfmathFunctions2ecfm1090027769$funcREDUCEBARBASE.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\controllers\ContentLogic\mathFunctions.cfm:711)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2471)
        at Statement26069.evaluate( :1)
        at coldfusion.compiler.ExprClassLoader.evaluate(ExprClassLoader.java:143)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.Evaluate(CFPage.java:1726)
        at cfContentLogic2ecfc1938419849$funcEVALUATEFUNCTIONSTRING.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\controllers\ContentLogic.cfc:479)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2436)
        at cfContentLogic2ecfc1938419849$funcFINDANDEVALUATE.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\controllers\ContentLogic.cfc:528)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2471)
        at cfContentLogic2ecfc1938419849$funcPREPAREDANSWERSBYQUESTIONIDQGID.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\controllers\ContentLogic.cfc:340)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2436)
        at cfContentLogic2ecfc1938419849$funcPROCESSDYNAMICITEMBYQUESTIONIDQGID.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\controllers\ContentLogic.cfc:69)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)
        at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:453)
        at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:320)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2222)
        at cfitemPackaging2ecfm1230617345$funcPREPAREDITEMBYQUESTIONIDQGID.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\controllers\ProtectedBusinessLogic\itemPackaging.cfm:693)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2436)
        at cfitemPackaging2ecfm1230617345$funcPREPAREDITEMSANDPASSAGESSTRUCTBYQGID.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\controllers\ProtectedBusinessLogic\itemPackaging.cfm:408)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2436)
        at cfitemPackaging2ecfm1230617345$funcPREPAREDITEMSANDPASSAGESSTRUCTBYQGIDS.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\controllers\ProtectedBusinessLogic\itemPackaging.cfm:73)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)
        at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:453)
        at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:320)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2222)
        at cfpracticesession2ecfm1218050444$funcPRACTICESESSION.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\controllers\Test\practicesession.cfm:272)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2436)
        at coldfusion.tagext.lang.InvokeTag.doEndTag(InvokeTag.java:432)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2662)
        at cfcfml2ecfm667848367$func$INVOKE.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\wheels\global\cfml.cfm:177)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2436)
        at cfprocessing2ecfm76711320$func$CALLACTION.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\wheels\controller\processing.cfm:85)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2436)
        at cfprocessing2ecfm76711320$func$PROCESSACTION.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\wheels\controller\processing.cfm:60)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
        at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:448)
        at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:308)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2272)
        at cfrequest2ecfm104933708$func$REQUEST.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\wheels\dispatch\request.cfm:166)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
        at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:448)
        at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:308)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2272)
        at cfindex2ecfm812783003.runPage(C:\SIWEB\cfw\wheels\index.cfm:1)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
        at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:370)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
        at cfrewrite2ecfm453288076.runPage(C:\SIWEB\cfw\rewrite.cfm:1)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
        at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:370)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
        at cfonrequest2ecfm951311187$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(C:\SIWEB\cfw\wheels\events\onrequest.cfm:1)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
        at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
        at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
        at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:448)
        at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:308)
        at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:74)
        at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:243)
        at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:269)
        at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
        at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
        at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)
        at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
        at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
        at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
        at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
        at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
        at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
        at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
        at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:175)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
        at com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.k(FusionReactorFilter.java:636)
        at com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.d(FusionReactorFilter.java:266)
        at com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorFilter.java:171)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
        at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
        at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
        at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
        at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
        at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
       Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

```
    Trace Time:   10:50:51.504 18-Sep-2012Thread ID:    0x19 (25)Thread Name:  jndi-3Priority:     5Hashcode:     290417686State:        RUNNABLE"jndi-3" prio=5 runnablejava.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:???)[Native Method]java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)jrun.servlet.network.NetworkService.accept(NetworkService.java:356)jrun.naming.NamingNetworkService.accept(NamingNetworkService.java:115)jrun.naming.NamingNetworkService.createRunnable(NamingNetworkService.java:141)jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.createRunnable(ThreadPool.java:287)jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.createRunnable(ThreadPool.java:349)jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.createRunnable(ThreadPool.java:241)jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:62)
```

Comment: These threads are BLOCKED which means they should be using any CPU. Can you find RUNNABLE threads?

Comment: There is probably a thread locked and causing the others to block. And because it doesnt unlock the monitor can never continue. I guess.

Comment: The stack traces you posted are of `Thread`s which are blocked, so not consuming any CPU at the moment.
The easiest way to discover which `Thread` (or `Thread`s) are using all you CPU is attaching a profiler to your application: examples of such profilers are JProfiler or even the freely available JVisualVM. You can also use some command-line utilities to discover the stack-trace of the `Thread` eating your CPU. Take a look at [this blogpost](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.be/2012/08/which-java-thread-consumes-my-cpu.html) for an example

Comment: > The noteworthy threads (so it would seem to me) are ones waiting for
> Monitors: Actually these are not noteworthy since they are in `WAITING` state and consume no CPU. You should inspect the `RUNNING` threads. Either some thread does something that is CPU-intensive (is that bad? can you improve it? *you* should know) or another that comes to mind is a live-lock. Your threads content for the CPU but no real progress is done. If your process finishes its job but just consumes too much CPU you can exclude the live-lock though.

Comment: So I am pretty sure this is the thread (last thread I posted) that is causing the blocks

Answer (score 0):

I'll second the recommendation to try JVisualVM - it is great for sorting through threads. Another good option is to use Eclipse, which will let you step through individual threads in debug mode as well.